# Configure CmakeLists.txt to avoid manually copying dlls

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm currently experimenting with the OpenCV library in C++. I've set up MinGW, CMake, and I'm coding in VSCode. However, I'm facing an inconvenience where I need to manually copy all the necessary DLL files into the project directory every time I want to run the executable program (.exe). Is there a configuration or setup that can help me avoid this constant copy-pasting of DLLs?

In CMakeLists.txt, I've already set:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR Path_to_opencv_lib)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

I'm unclear about why we need to copy DLLs into the current project directory in the first place.

Any assistance with these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can either add the existing dll's folder to your PATH, or add a CMake [post build command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) to copy them automatically to the target folder.

Comment: So, does it mean that either way the dlls are gonna be copied to current project directory?

Comment: No, in case you add them to the PATH they will beloaded from there. I added a complete answer explaining it.

Comment: @starball the OP does not necessarily wish to copy the DLLs to the target folder (which is what the duplicate is about). They actually seem to prefer not to. In my answer I listed both options. Please consider to reopen.

Comment: @wohlstad "manually copy". as for their deeper understanding problem, they should read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order and related SO Q&A about DLL search. assuming they are doing dev work and not testing from install tree, I think modifying PATH is overkill

Comment: @wohlstad I don't see how the asker's comment above is defining in any way about their question. if anything, it just furthers an image that they are lacking some foundational knowledge. in any case, their question is "_Is there a configuration or setup that can help me avoid this constant copy-pasting of DLLs?_", and the dup-target does answer that question. even if you are adamant that that is not their question, I'm sure whatever their question is has already been asked before, and it would be better for you to search for what you think is an appropriate dup-target for that question.

Comment: @wohlstad and starball , thank you for replies. I'll read again the provided sources. Yeah, I indeed lack of understanding DLLs search in Windows. 

PS. I have already added OpenCV directory to PATH. But if one of trivial solutions is to add DLLs' directory to PATH, then does it mean that every newly installed library's DLLs should be also added to PATH?

Comment: I think many people design their software packages for Windows such that their DLLs are installed in the same directory as their executables, so only one directory needs to be added to the path for all the programs in the software package. You don't add binary files to PATH. you add directories containing binaries.